# How can I automatically save the Dell iDRAC boot capture videos?

Tags: dell, boot, drac

The Dell iDRAC automatically records video of the last three boot sequences on the server. These videos can be played back via the iDRAC web interface. The web interface also offers a "save" button to download the video locally. I would like to automatically save these videos.

In particular, I have a couple labs of Dell servers with iDRAC that I use for automated testing. We reboot the machines frequently and sometimes they get "stuck" which causes delays in our automation. About 75% of the time, a power cycle clears the error. I would like to save the boot video before automatically cycling the power.

The RACADM tool appears to let me enable/disable the creation of the videos but doesn't let me download the videos...

Any thoughts?